# Is there a way to select all permissions in one click when issuing a Facebook user access token

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to select all options in one click? It seems tiresome to individually click each one.

[image]

Comment: what for? for testing, it´s better to check only permissions you need anyway, to make sure you are asking for the correct ones. the only app that may be good for that is the graph api explorer app.

Comment: for testing obviously. I would not try to introduce friction by asking for more than what I need.